# Adding two identical nodes to different HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement

I am creating a table using createElement, for example:

```
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
```

I create the body, rows, and cells the same way. I want to output the exact same table to two different HTML elements. Let's called them ele1 and ele2.

```
var elements = ['ele1', 'ele2'];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   tbl.id = "table_" + i; //set the ID so they differ for each table instance
   document.getElementById(ele).appendChild(tbl);
}
```

However, the table only ever appears in the last element. I can't figure out how to duplicate the tables.

I've I create the ENTIRE table from scratch for EVERY element it works but I am trying to avoid unnecessary processing.

Comment: `.appendChild()` will move an element. You have to "clone" a node if you want a copy of it.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cloneNode`:

```
document.getElementById(ele).appendChild(tbl.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: I was hoping something like this would exist! Can I use clone node even on single nodes or do I have to ascertain that I need more than one before using?

Comment: Its for whichever node you want to append, as pointed out in comments, using appendChild will only move your node around. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Comment: Thank you! You have my eternal gratitude